# PRNG concatenation

Tags: random, cryptography

I would like to know if there is a difference between these two points:

- a PRNG generating 256 bits
- a PRNG generating 8 times 32 bits and concatenating them

In theory, I don't think there's a difference but with a PRNG which could not be optimal. Which one do you prefer and why ?

Comment: Do you mean a [CSPRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator) (Cryptographically Secure Psuedo Random Number Generator)?

Comment: Essentially there's no difference. In general terms, the predictability of a PRNG depends more on the number of bits that it uses to maintain its state. For example, RC4 uses a state array of 2048 bits (256 bytes) but produces 8 bits at each iteration, while the `rand()` function in glibc uses 31 state bits and outputs 31 bits at each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

If you need 256 bit you should go with option one and calculate the random bytes in one go.

A PRNG usually calculates its random data in blocks which are almost always larger than 32 bits. So if you request 32 bit 8 times, the RNG will a) have to do more calculations and b) drop random data which is has calculated but was not requested by you.

This might turn into a security problem if you do this a lot of times (millions of time and more) and are not able to reseed the PRNG.